# Probability distribution of distances between randomly elected numbers?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions, stochastic-processes

Assume that a list is generated as follows. Each natural number is included in the list with a given probability p. Let G be the gap between two numbers (gap 1 is zero to number 1 gap two is distance between number one to number two an so on) in this list.

What is the probability distribution for G, that is, the value of Pr(G = i), for all i ∈ N.

Ideas i have so far:

$$
Pr(G = 1) = p\\ 
Pr(G = 2) = (1-p)\cdot p\\
Pr(G = 3) = (1-p)^2\cdot p\\
\vdots\\
Pr(G = i) = (1-p)^{i-1}\cdot p\\
$$

Is this correct? is this a probability distribution?

Comment: "Aside from this example. Is there a general way to determine a probability distribution?" No. (It is a universal fact that universal questions rarely have meaningful answers.)

Comment: Does this fit the rules?